# Build GraphPath from list of vertices

Tags: java, graph, path, jgrapht

Is there a way in which I can build a `GraphPath` of one graph using just its list of vertices to create a path from another graph in `SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph`?

For example, lets say i do a `.getVertexList()` on a path from `tempGraph`and i wish to build a path from the `mainGraph`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Please improve the clarity of your question. It is not clear what it is that you exactly need. Also include a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean making marge `mainGraph` and `tempGraph`  into one

In this case, add all `vertices` and `edges` from one graph to the other graph, then you could choose any `vertex` from both graphs to connect